# Submit Qt based app on Windows App

Tags: qt, windows

I have already created Qt based application which uses some third-party open source library like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), I have looked  [Windows Dev Center](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted) and seems the all the reference is using Visual Studios and other Windows tool. I have created my App using Qt creator. Is it possible to submit such an application on Windows App store?

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks
Haris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news: Microsoft does not support Win32 apps on AppStore yet (but it has been announced, currently under development as "Project Centennial"). It looks like an "old-school" desktop applications cannot be submitted to the Windows App store.

Good news: Qt has support for WinRT (complete in Qt 5.6 which is currently in Beta and will be released in a few weeks). And `qmake` can generate a Visual Studio solution from your project (in case you need it for deployment or debugging; VS Community edition is free).

Qt WinRT tutorial: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/winrt-support.html

OpenCV in WinRT: https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/03/20/easily-build-opencv-powered-apps-for-windows-store/

Comment: So if I port the Qt project to Visual studio using qmake still will it be Win32, can I submit it?.

Comment: No, you will have to port it to WinRT. How difficult it would be depends on what Win32 APIs your application uses. But Qt and OpenCV support it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found you tube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pTeysNkRkk which seems similar situation. Following it, downloaded `Qt5.6.0 beta for Windows runtime 64 bit` and installed it, and I can build and run normal qt example fine with metro style, where as including OpenCV lib creates some error like `CoCreateInstanceFromApp': indentifier not found` trying to solve it. Do you have any idea why this error?

Comment: Check this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e013fe26-4c2d-442f-96eb-ce17c3ee35f3/metro-ap-create-a-c-opencv-application-error-cocreateinstancefromapp-identifier-not-found?forum=winappswithnativecode There they have `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601`. Changing it to `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0602` solved the issue

Comment: Also, I am linking OpenCV library build for x64 platform with my WinRT project, I think I need to recompile OpenCV for WinRT.

Comment: Microsoft now has a system to allow 32-bit apps on the app store. See "Desktop Bridge", tho look at limitations, you might need minor adjustments before you can do it: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop